# How to use table name different then in database in cake php 3

Tags: model, cakephp-3.0

I am using cake php 3.4.
I have guest and country table in database.
I want to access these table object as Guests and Contries.

I want to use like this :

```
$this->Guests->find();
```

instead of

```
$this->Guest->find()
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a [model](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#basic-usage) **GuestsTable.php** in **src/Model/Table/**

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class GuestsTable extends Table
{

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->setTable('guest'); // your table name

        // Prior to 3.4.0
        // $this->table('guest');
    }

}
```

Same goes for country

Comment: Its looking great may be my problem will be solved. Thanks for this and I will do the same and then check.